# How to improve the performance of my custom function for getting fast results?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I;m using Lucene/.NET to implement a numerical search engine.

I want to filter numbers from within a large range, depends on which number exists in string array.

I used the following code:

```
int startValue = 1; 
endValue = 100000;

//Assume that the following string array contains 12000 strings
String[] ArrayOfTerms = new String[] { "1", "10",................. , "99995"};

public String[] GetFilteredStrings(String[] ArrayOfTerms)
{
  List<String> filteredStrings = new List<String>();

  for (int i = startValue; i <= endValue; i++)
  {                       
     int index = Array.IndexOf(ArrayOfTerms,i.ToString());

     if( index != -1)
     {
        filteredStrings.Add((String)ArrayOfTerms.GetValue(index));
     }      
  }

return filteredStrings.ToArray();

}
```

Now, my problem is it searches every value from 1 to 100000 and takes too much time. some times my application is hanging.

Can anyone of you help me how to improve this performance issue? I don't know about caching concept, but I know that Lucene supports cache filters. Should I use a cache filter? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you're trying to determine if an Array contains the item or not.
I think you should use something like a HashSet or Dictionary to be able to determine presence of the value for O(1) time instead of O(n) time you have.

Answer (score 0):

This code works pretty much faster.

```
var results = ArrayOfTerms.Where(s => int.Parse(s) <= endValue);
```

If I got what you want to do

Comment: What does `<= endValue` mean/do?

Comment: Less or equal than endValue variable

Comment: Oh, I thought it was some kind of reverse lambda operator!